# stty --help returns illegal option on macOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, stty

I'm trying to learn `stty` for serial port communication. But whenever I run some commands including `stty --help` it returns:

> stty: illegal option -- --help
>
> usage: stty [-a|-e|-g] [-f file] [options]

I also tried `man stty | grep help` with no results returned and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNSZmSQSDYwYQn9QYp9erd3d-YXi1g%3A1572213408332&ei=oBK2XYLxE4P5wQL3-qfYBg&q=stty%20illegal%20option&oq=stty%20illegal%20option&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13l2.10260.24064..24818...0.0..0.54.132.3......0....1..gws-wiz.bt74AUqehaU&ved=0ahUKEwiCwdutt73lAhWDfFAKHXf9CWsQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) doesn't help much either. There are two possibilities I can think of:

- macOS's stty is different from the one on Linux. It seems like macOS's stty is from BSD. I would give you the version if `stty --version` would work!
- there is something wrong with my environment settings `bash_profile`/`bashrc`

**P.S.1.** I asked here instead of [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) because I couldn't find a `stty` tag over there.

**P.S.2.** On bash IRC channel I was told that:

> --help is a GNUism, which is why OSX's stty doesn't recognize

and that

> there are a subset of options and operands that work across the two implementations. You can see what those are [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html)

Comment: Is that *Catalina*?

Comment: @RichardBarber no, it is Mojave.